# SQL: how to speed up a conditional join?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm doing a conditional join where I'm joining to one table if the condition is met, but to another table if not. This is painfully slow; is there a way to optimize the query to speed it up?

The tables look like this (simplified):

```
Subscriptions:
user_ID, subscription_ID, status
96, 254, Active
77, 777, Expired

Users:
user_ID
18
77
99

Seats:
user_ID, subscription_ID
18, 254
18, 222
22, 333
22, 444
```

The task is: given a user_ID from **Users**, try to get the subscription status from **Subscriptions**; but, if that user_ID isn’t in **Subscriptions**, look up all its possible subscription numbers in **Seats** and try finding those in **Subscriptions** instead. If no subscription is found, keep the user_ID in the results with Nulls for the other columns. For example, user_ID 18 isn't in **Subscriptions**, but I can still get its status by seeing that it has subscription 254 in **Seats** and looking that up instead.

Desired result:

```
user_ID, subscription_ID, status
18, 254, Active
77, 777, Expired
99, Null, Null
```

I can't just look up all the userIDs in **Seats** and get around the conditional join that way, because most of them aren't in that table. I can't change the table schemas.

I think this query does what I want:

```
select * from users
left join seats on users.user_ID=seats.user_ID
left join subscriptions on 
(case when seats.subscription_ID is null then users.user_ID=facts.user_ID
else seats.subscription_ID=subscriptions.subscription_ID end)
```

But these tables are large and it's taking unfeasibly long to complete. What would be a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you share sample data in text instead of pictures? This will help people who want to try a rewrite to test it. Also, although the output here is pretty clear, it's always a good idea to have an intended output table so people answering can check their math.

Comment: You are better off joining facts twice for the two different cases and using coalesce in the selected fields.  As is, no index can be used and every facts record has to be evaluated as a possible join for each jag/seats or jag with no seats combination.

Comment: @TKR I didn't downvote but changing your sample data to markdown tables, adding the relevant DDL and adding explain output would improve the question. Statements like "painfully slow" aren't helpful as we have no idea what qualifies as "painfully slow" in your context. Adding the execution time is more useful.

Comment: Also, snowflake sql does not have the same syntax as MySQL; choose one or the other for your questions.  (I didn't downvote either)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the method suggested by ysth with the two joins to `Subscriptions` and the use of [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in the select list -

```
select
    u.user_ID,
    coalesce(subs1.subscription_ID, subs2.subscription_ID) subscription_ID,
    coalesce(subs1.status, subs2.status) status
from Users u
left join Subscriptions subs1
    on u.user_ID = subs1.user_ID
left join seats
    on subs1.user_ID is null and u.user_ID = seats.user_ID
left join Subscriptions subs2
    on seats.subscription_ID = subs2.subscription_ID
where not(seats.user_ID is not null and subs2.subscription_ID is null);
```

If this still takes "unfeasibly long to complete", please add your `CREATE TABLE` statements and the EXPLAIN output for the query to your question.

Answer (score 2):

join twice and `union all` then together, if you know they will not pull the rows in twice (on both sides) and if they would, add the anti match.

```
select * from jag
left join seats 
    on jag.userID = seats.userID
left join facts 
    on seats.sub is null and  jag.userID = facts.userID

union all

select * from jag
left join seats 
    on jag.userID=seats.userID
left join facts 
    on seats.sub is not null and seats.sub = facts.sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain/show what you mean by adding the anti match? Also, why not use *union* instead of *union all* to get rid of dupes that way?

Comment: You only EVERY use `UNION` if you want the deduplication step, but that is expensive. Thus if your wanting "performance" avoid costly steps..